# Why is this program running so slowly?

Tags: java, performance

This is for project euler problem 14.

When a number is even, you're supposed to divide the number by two, but when it is odd you multiply it by three and add one. Eventually it should reach one.

My task is to find the number that takes the largest amount of steps to get to 1.

Here's my code:

```
    int currentNum = 0;
    int iterator = 0;
    int[] largestChain = new int[]{0,0};
    for(int i = 10;i<=1000000;i++)
    {
        currentNum = i;
        iterator = 0;
        while(currentNum!=1)
        {
            iterator++;
            if(currentNum%2==0)
            {
                currentNum/=2;
            }
            else
            {
                currentNum = (currentNum*3)+1;
            }
        }
        if(iterator>largestChain[1])
        {
            largestChain[0] = i;
            largestChain[1] = iterator;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("largest iterator:"+largestChain[1]+"for num:"+largestChain[0]);
```

Can you please help me out by telling me what's slowing it down? (It's taking >30 minutes right now and it still hasn't come up with the answer).

Comment: Hint: use a better algorithm

Comment: Hint: You're re-calculating the same sequences many times.  Whenever you calculate a sequence, store it.  When calculating future sequences, as soon as you find a value for which you've already calculated then use the stored value.

Comment: If you still want to stick to same logic, see if you can implement threads to do the job.

Comment: Strangely enough, my implementation I did a while ago for this looks pretty similar yet finishes in < 1 sec... Wonder what's going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `long` variables instead of `int`. `currentNum` goes so high the values wrap around into the negatives!

Once you do that change, your algorithm works just fine. (I tested it)

Comment: Good point, the overflow could be resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: If not infinite, it at least creates a VERY very long loop. And besides, it invalidates the results.

Comment: Thanks so much! Switching it to long worked perfectly; I need to be more careful with my variable types..

Answer (score 0):

The reason it take so long is that you are performing this while loop operation on 1 million numbers. The solution to this is to create an algorithm which saves the number of steps dynamically.

```
int[] steps = new int[1000000];
steps[0] = 0;
steps[1] = 1;
```

Iterate through the rest of your numbers, adding back to this base case. By the end, many of your paths will be computed, and you will not need a nested loop.

---

However, if you want to stick to your way:
I'd recommend putting some debug print statements in there to see where it is getting caught up. My guess is that the 1 Million looped while statements are the culprit, but the easiest way to find out is progress check.

try adding `System.out.println(i+":");` before the while and `System.out.println("     current number: "+currentnum);` inside the while.

Should print out something like:

```
1:
     1
2:
     2
     1
```

etc.

Comment: This is going to create *a lot* of output.  And all it's going to do is indicate what's already known... the algorithm is inefficient in large loops.

Comment: Yes it is, and yes we do. The algorithm is just huge, but if that is okay with OP, this will indicate that it is at least running. I will edit my answer to indicate finding a new algorithm is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code to print the interesting info and how its looping. The loop is crazy. 
I would suggest converting currentNum to 'long' and re-run it as that number goes negative (beyond int capacity).

```
public class TestLoop{
public static void main(String[] args){
int currentNum = 0;
int iterator = 0;
int[] largestChain = new int[]{0,0};
for(int i = 10;i<=1000000;i++)
{
    currentNum = i;
    iterator = 0;
    System.out.println("\nCurrently Running :" + i);
    while(currentNum!=1)
    {
        iterator++;
        if(currentNum%2==0)
        {
            currentNum/=2;
        }
        else
        {
            currentNum = (currentNum*3)+1;
        }
            System.out.print(currentNum + " ");
    }
    if(iterator>largestChain[1])
    {
        largestChain[0] = i;
        largestChain[1] = iterator;
     }
  }

System.out.println("\nLargest iterator: "+largestChain[1]+" for num:"+largestChain[0]);
 }
}
```

I ran it on linux and got below answer in 10 mins after I changed the currentNum to 'long'.

Largest iterator: 524 for num:837799

Still there is a flaw in your logic: you are NOT checking if any other number taking the same iterations. E.g. below loop gives two such numbers :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class TestLoop {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long currentNum;
    int iterator;
    int[] largestChain = new int[]{0, 0};
    ArrayList Nums = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 10; i <= 300; i++) {
        currentNum = i;
        iterator = 0;
        System.out.println("\nCurrently Running :" + i);
        while (currentNum != 1) {
            iterator++;
            if (currentNum % 2 == 0) {
                currentNum /= 2;
            } else {
                currentNum = (currentNum * 3) + 1;
            }
            System.out.print(currentNum + " ");
        }
        if (iterator > largestChain[1]) {
            largestChain[0] = i;
            largestChain[1] = iterator;
            Nums.clear();
            Nums.add(i);
        } else if (iterator == largestChain[1]) {
            Nums.add(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\nLargest iterator: " + largestChain[1]);
    //+ " for num:" + largestChain[0]);
    if (Nums.size() == 1) {
        System.out.println("There is only one number with " + largestChain[1] + " iterations:" + largestChain[0]);
    } else {
        System.out.print("Below numbers took " + largestChain[1] + " iterations:");
        for (int i = 0; i < Nums.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + Nums.get(i));
        }
    }

 }
}
```